# Moving folder location of Expression Blend 3 Silverlight project causes embedded fonts to not work

Tags: silverlight, expression-blend, embedded-fonts

I made an expression blend 3 project with embedded fonts, then copied the whole solution folder to a different location on my computer.  When I open the copy at the new location default fonts are used for all the spots that used to be embedded fonts.  When I open the original, the fonts are fine.  The embedded fonts folder is in the project directory and was copied along with it, and all references to the fonts that I was able to find were relative paths.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: More details needed, its sounds like you are doing every thing fine but clearly you aren't.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it and wasn't able to recreate your bug, unfortunately. Copying the project to a new location worked just fine.

Did anything else change, like the folder structure of your project? There's a bug right now where BlendEmbeddedFont paths are relative to the XAML file where the Style is set, not where its defined.